# Appending values to c array

Tags: c, arrays

This is a very simple question, but I don't know how to do this.

For example, I have an array called `Array`containing the values`[1,2,3,4,5,6]`, and I want to add a seventh value, `7`, to the array so it contains`[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]`.

Is there a function to do that? Do I need to include any extra header files? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It is not possible or add elements dynamically size is already determined when the declared array. So either set aside in advance the size with a margin that can be added, to be copied and add used as an alternative to the array area secured by `malloc(calloc or realloc)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is a plain array declared as such:

```
int Array[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
```

Then you wouldn't be able to add more values to it. If there's some space provided in advance then you may add more values:

```
int Array[7] = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
Array[6] = 7;
```

If you used c++, I would recommend using std::vector, but it does not exist in C.

Answer (score 1):

Nope.  No information is stored about the size of, or the number of occupied elements, of an array in C.  You could devise a struct and a procedure that did this, but the language does not do it for you.

```
struct cvector
{
    int *content;
    int occupied;
    int size;
};

void cvector_init(struct cvector *v)
{
    v->content = malloc(sizeof *(v->content) * 16;
    v->size = 16;
    v->occupied = 0;
}

void cvector_kill(struct cvector *v)
{
    free(v->content);
}

// returns true if an error occurred, as is the style with linux syscalls.
int cvector_append(struct cvector *v, int value)
{
    if (v->occupied == v->size)
    {
        int new_size = v->size * 1.75;
        int *new_content = realloc(v->content, new_size);
        if (new_content == NULL) return 1;
        v->content = new_content;
        v->size = new_size;
    }
    v->content[v->occupied++] = value;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the malloc and realloc functions from `<stdlib.h>` for this. The basic idea is to allocate a certain amount of space up front, and then enlarge the array when you discover that it is not big enough.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int *append(int size, int a[size], int value){
    int *ret = malloc((size+1)*sizeof(int));
    memcpy(ret, a, size*sizeof(int));
    ret[size] = value;
    return ret;
}
int main(void){
    int Array[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
    int size = sizeof(Array)/sizeof(*Array);
    int *a = append(size++, Array, 7);
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<size;i++){
        printf("%d\n", a[i]);
    }
    free(a);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is confusing. With consecutive calls of `append`, it is leaking memory. Besides, why not use a pointer from the start and then `realloc` directly?

Comment: @undur_gongor _With consecutive calls of append, it is leaking memory._ It is erroneous usage of course.

Comment: _why not use a pointer from the start and then realloc directly?_ It is because it is assumed that an array is passed.

Comment: Yes, that's true. But you are not appending to the array, though. At least some explanation what you are doing and how your `append` is supposed to be used seems appropriate.

Comment: @undur_gongor That the addition of the elements of change the size in the array can not be is a comment already. This is a code sample of as an alternative to the array of using that malloc in the comment.